# Copy tables into database

Tags: sql-server

I imported data from Power BI into SQL-Server. You can see how is look like imported data.

[image]

Additionally I created own database with commands below:

```
CREATE DATABASE MY_DW
GO

USE MY_DW
GO
```

Now I want to copy all this table into my base named as MY_DW. So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and copy all tables into my base ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following approach could resolve your issue:

- Imported Database

  - Generate Scripts

    - Introduction
    - Next button
    - Select the database objects (Tables in your case) to script
    - Next button
    - Specify how scripts should be saved

      - Advanced -> Types of data to script -> Schema and data
    - Next button
    - Review your selections
    - Next button
    - Script generation would take place and saved which you should run under the database,
      MY_DW, you created

**Another approach:**

Assuming that the databases are in the same server.

The below query will create the table into your database(without constraints).

```
SELECT * INTO MY_DW.Table_Name 
FROM ImportedDB.Table_Name
```

And the below query will insert the data into your database table.

```
INSERT INTO MY_DW.Table_Name 
SELECT * FROM ImportedDB.Table_Name
```

**Final approach:**

Assuming that the databases are in the linked server.

Incase of linked server, four part database object naming convention will be applied like below.

The below query will create the table into your database(without constraints).

```
SELECT * INTO [DestinationServer].[MY_DW].[dbo].[Table_Name] 
FROM [SourceServer].[ImportedDB].[dbo].[Table_Name]
```

And the below query will insert the data into your database table.

```
INSERT INTO [DestinationServer].[MY_DW].[dbo].[Table_Name]  
SELECT * FROM [SourceServer].[ImportedDB].[dbo].[Table_Name]
```

Comment: I  can't generate scripts because I don't have Task option when I click right button of the mouse. Please if you have other suggest me other approach

Comment: Please check "Another approach" in the answer I edited :)

Comment: Thank you a lot about this and is clear for me how to dial with data if the data are on same server. But in my case this data is on localhost: 59307 while, other database is on different server and I want to copy all table from this localhost and move into different server eg. DESKTOP-2IIMTUR\SQLEXPRESS where is my database named as MY_DW. I also try with select *
from [Eurostat_TPS00170] in order to see table but I make some mistake in this. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Oh! then may be you need to use `linked server`. Please check "Final approach" in the answer I just edited :)

Comment: @Salahuddion Ahmed Can you check this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68000992/copy-tables-from-one-server-to-another?noredirect=1#comment120191362_68000992

Comment: @silent_hunter, it seems same issue, however, can you please clarify what problem you are facing for your new question or does not the answer of this old question help out there?

Answer (score 2):

Please check https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server/.

This link suggests various methods to copy the data tables from one database to another.

Thanks,

Rajan